# Translation of Soergel's 1990 paper on category O

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, translation, category-o

Is there any English translation for the folowing paper of Soergel?

> *Kategorie $\mathcal{O}$, perverse Garben, und Moduln über den Koinvarianten zur Weylgruppe*, J. Amer. Math. Soc. **3** (1990), 421-445, doi:[10.1090/S0894-0347-1990-1029692-5](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-1990-1029692-5)

Any (English) reference for proofs of its main theorems is also welcome.

Comment: I don't know of one. A summary of the main theorems (on the category O side) are here:
http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/geordie/aarhus/lectures/4.3.pdf
The geometric side is outlined at a rate of knots here:
http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/geordie/aarhus/lectures/3.4.pdf

Comment: Thanks! Are these lecture notes included in part of your joint paper with Ben Elias?

Comment: ... no, but Elias, Makisumi, Thiel and I have almost finished editing a collection of lecture notes written by members of a summer school at MSRI. The book should be available soon and will have much more detail (in English).