# On Soergel's results concerning projectives modules in category $\mathcal{O}$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, translation, category-o

I am looking for a translated proof of two results of Soergel usually referred to as *endomorphismensatz* and *struktursatz*.

Both of those results were shown in the paper

> Soergel, W. (1990). Kategorie , perverse Garben und Moduln über den Koinvarianten zur Weylgruppe. Journal of the American Mathematical Society, 3(2), 421-445

but I can't find a proof written in English. A previous post (see [Translation of Soergel's 1990 paper on category O](https://mathoverflow.net/q/323179/158730)) asked for a translation of the whole paper, but it is still unanswered. Moreover, I could not find a proof in the book *Introduction to Soergel bimodules* despite a comment made in the aforementioned post.

Any help is appreciated.